# Enable the CustomSMSSender for 3rd party provider to send SMS verification code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I want to send verification code provided by aws cognito to sms using third party provider. I was going through some documentation.
[aws documenation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-sms-sender.html)

But I couldnot find the CustomSMSSender trigger option. Here

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you go up a level on the documentation ([this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-sender-triggers.html)), it says:

> You can use the AWS CLI or SDK to configure your user pools to use these Lambda triggers. These configurations aren't available from Amazon Cognito console.

You need to setup a KMS key and a Lambda function, then use AWS CLI to add the trigget: `aws cognito-idp update-user-pool --user-pool-id ##POOL_ID## --lambda-config "CustomSMSSender={LambdaVersion=V1_0,LambdaArn=##LAMBDA_ARN##},KMSKeyID=##KMS_KEY_ARN##"`

Also make sure you have the correct role setup in IAM, or the above command will fail.

p.s. the above command will reset cognito pool settings to default values (because didn't provide other params), remember to set them back to what you have before.
Here is the command to dump pool settings to json: `aws cognito-idp describe-user-pool --user-pool-id ##POOL_ID## --query UserPool > backup.json`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create function in lambda (AWS LAMBDA)and you need to call the function @ pre signup or create auth challange ...etc

check the below link:
https://techinscribed.com/passwordless-phone-number-authentication-using-aws-amplify-cognito/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).